# How to use regex to match both filename and file content in Linux?

Tags: regex, linux

I want to find files that contain the word 'virus' but not 'antivirus' (case insensitive) in both their filename and their content.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -i -P --exclude='*[aA][nN][tT][iI][vV][iI][rR][uU][sS]*' '(?<!anti)virus' *[vV][iI][rR][uU][sS]*
```

`(?<!anti)` is a negative lookbehind that prevents matching the following pattern if it's preceded by `anti`.

The above operates just in the current directory. If you need to search subdirectories recursively, use:

```
grep -P -r -i --include='*[vV][iI][rR][uU][sS]*' --exclude='*[aA][nN][tT][iI][vV][iI][rR][uU][sS]*' '(?<!anti)virus' .
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is this case sensitive? I tested it and it skips Antivirus

Comment: Yes. Add `-i` to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to make filename patterns case-insensitive. You have to write `*[vV][iI][rR][uU][sS]*`

Comment: Thank you so much. No idea why my question is closed, but at least I learned something.

Comment: Probably because you didn't show your attempt. Also, this is off-topic, it would be more appropriate for [unix.se].